# mechanical turk -- how to train a knowledge worker for a qualification?

Tags: survey, mechanicalturk

I am new to mTurk and I am trying to create a Qualification Test that first trains workers in how to perform a task, and then tests the worker on what they learned. If the worker passes the test, the worker can then continue onto the tasks.

How would I create a multi-page Qualification Test with (1) a training page with examples that the worker can view and (2) a testing page similar to the Qualification Test?

I thought about posting the training page on a different website and linking to it, but ideally I would like the worker to not be able to access the training page while their knowledge is being tested. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Qualification Tests are, by definition, one page and non-dynamic. What you describe will require that you create a HIT as a training activity and then, based on performance on that, assign qualifications that will allow satisfactory workers to complete the actual HITs. The QuestionForm structure that needs to be used for creating a QualificationTest is simply not flexible enough for your needs. The only option within that model would be - as you describe - to actually host the training activity off-site.